# Present perfect simple vs present perfect progressive

Tags: grammar, tense, present-tense

Why we use the present perfect rather than the present perfect progressive?

Example:

Passengers who (have spent) days sleeping on the airport floor are perplexed as to why only one third of flights are leaving.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either there. *Have been spending days sleeping* is a little awkward because of the repeated *-ing*, but it's perfectly possible.

I think *have spent* is more natural, but *have been spending* puts more emphasis on how the activity continued through time, which you might well wish to do in this particular sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Colin`s answer I would like to say that "to spend" is often used with present perfect. "Days" can be viewed as a duration of time = how long, which requires the present perfect continuous , but it can also be viewed as an amount of time = how much, which requires the present perfect simple.